# Error about agpgart during startup on Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, boot, startup

I have started to notice a strange  error quickly flash across my screen every time I boot my laptop running Fedora 20. I'm not sure what it means or how it may be affecting my system, but I figured it would be best to address it ASAP before I have problems that could be because of this.

Here's what flashes across the screen during startup:

```
Booting 'Fedora (3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64) 20 (Heisenbug)'
[    1.887874] [drm:drm_pci_agp_init]  =ERROR= Cannot initialize the agpgart module.
[    1.887932] DRM: Fill_in_dev failed.
```

My question is, **what all does this mean and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### My output

I'm on Fedora 19 and I get these messages.

```
$ dmesg | less
[    0.898072] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.898214] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: Intel HD Graphics Chipset
[    0.898439] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 2097152K total, 262144K mappable
[    0.899719] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected 32768K stolen memory
[    0.899978] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 256M @ 0xd0000000
```

#### Potential solutions

I found this ArchLinux forum thread titled: "[[SOLVED] drm_pci_agp_init *ERROR* Cannot initialize the agpgart module](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173771)". The solutions discussed in the thread suggest either blacklisting that module or removing drm module.

*excerpt*

> SOLVED: I finally found a way how to disable the driver by removing drm.ko.gz:
>
> ```
>    cd /lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/
>    rm drm.ko.gz
> ```
>
> Alternatively, I can prevent any modules from loading by adding blacklist parameter in the boot entries:
>
> ```
>    blacklist=module#1,module#2,module#n
> ```
>
> Another solution is that I simply removed the nomodeset parameter from my boot entries:
>
> ```
>    title Arch
>    linux /vmlinuz-linux
>    initrd /initramfs-linux.img
>    options cryptdevice=UUID=<UUID>:<dm_name> root=/dev/mapper/<dm_name> [del]nomodeset[/del]
> ```

#### What's agpgart?

The wikipedia page discusses what agpgart is in this topic titled: [Graphics address remapping table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_address_remapping_table).